# implementing multiple classes using same misused database table

Tags: c#-4.0

probably a stupid and simple question from a junior developer.

I have a database where the same table is used for multiple purposes. Now I want to implement multiple classes using this tables. Functionality is the same for each class only variable names have to be different (for readabiliy and understanding).

Is this possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

yes, why not?
Thats the sense of functions and parameters:D